# Codeigniter Where Or from previous Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following query:

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->where('barcode != ""');
$codes = $this->db->get('acquisti')->result();
return $codes;
```

This produces a result (varius fields) that can show one or more records, I need to tell Codeigniter to show FROM ANOTHER TABLE the results where "barcode" is one of the record found above.

I tried this:

```
$this->db->where('user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->where('barcode != ""');
$codes = $this->db->get('acquisti')->result();

foreach ($codes as $key => $value) {
    $this->db->where('IRSC', $value->barcode);
    return $this->db->get('rendiconti_agosto')->result();
}
```

But this returns only ONE result even if the `$code` is actually more than one.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to catch them in `array` and then return them like

```
foreach ($codes as $key => $value) {
    $this->db->where('IRSC', $value->barcode);
    $result_arr[] = $this->db->get('rendiconti_agosto')->result();
}
return $result_arr;
```

In your code you are return for the first time of loop so the loop will terminated at first and then results only the first result that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can do it without loop.

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("acquisti a");
$this->db->join("rendiconti_agosto ra","ra.IRSC = a.barcode ");
$this->db->where('a.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$this->db->where('a.barcode <> ""');
$res = $this->db->get();    
return $res->result_array();
```